# Событие Onclick скачать а не открыть файл

Tags: html

имеется button

```html
<button onclick="location.href='https://saita.net/file.pdf'" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button">Click me</button>
```

какой вызов параметра нужно вызвать, для скачки файла а не открытия.

Comment: Добавьте атрибут download="путь к файлу"

Comment: И тег должен быть a по моему

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, у кнопки нет такого атрибута.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать тег <`form`>:

```
<form method="GET" action="/path_to_file.file">
   <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Либо:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('/path_to_file.file')">Download!</button>
```

Также вы можете стилизовать ссылку как кнопку и использовать:

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="file_name">Download</a>
```

Comment: у меня кнопка со счётчиком и скачивание работает только с событием onclick="location.href= –

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно атрибута download у ссылки

Comment: у меня кнопка со счётчиком и скачивание работает только с событием onclick="location.href=